# Auto format numbers in org-mode spreadsheets

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is there any way to automatically force number of decimal places in an org-mode spreadsheet? So that 42 would be changed to 43.00 when I move to the next field?

Also, is there automatic formatting for thousands separators?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want a field to auto-format when changing to the next one, you would need to use the auto-update row header `#` to indicate that fields in that row should auto-calc whenever `TAB` `S-TAB` or `RET` are pressed in that row (see [Org-Manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-features.html#Advanced-features)).

Then if you include as a formula for that cell (I'm assuming that if you are wanting to enter the value manually you will not have a formula affecting that cell usually) that contains (for your 42 -> 42.00 example)

```
=$0;%.2f
```

Information before the = sign can be cell or column references depending if you want the formula to be applied to a single cell or to the entire column.  (This is mentioned [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Formula-syntax-for-Calc.html#Formula-syntax-for-Calc))

I wasn't able to find any reference to thousands separators in org, it might not be possible at the moment.

Comment: This is a lot of help, especially the auto-update row headers - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This link on [Formula Syntax for Calc](http://orgmode.org/manual/Formula-syntax-for-Calc.html#Formula-syntax-for-Calc) shows the various options for `org-calc-default-modes`, which will allow you to change the display format and precision.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you in any way?

```
(setq org-calc-default-modes '(calc-internal-prec 12
    calc-float-format (float 9)
    calc-angle-mode deg
    calc-prefer-frac nil
    calc-symbolic-mode nil
    calc-date-format (YYYY "-" MM "-" DD " " Www (" " HH ":" mm))
    calc-display-working-message t))
```